# PHP Regex - Remove second-level domain

Tags: php, regex

I am using this code which works fine in stripping the `http://` part.

```
<?php $str = get_field('fl_website');$str = preg_replace('#^https?://www.#', '', rtrim($str,'/'));echo $str; ?>
```

However I need to also strip any second-level links and only keep the main domain name.

For example:

```
https://www.example.com/sites/annabel/2016/03
```

needs to be converted to just:

```
example.com
```

Comment: I think it might work as my input is always a URL

Comment: Use `$domain = str_ireplace('www.', '', parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST))`.